# Displaying data with JavaScript works in a textarea but not in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble displaying data that is pulled from a form input to my div tag. The data displays when I use `textarea` but as soon as add the ID to my div the data doesn't display.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<div id="input">
    <input rows="1" name="q"  id="GoogleURLtextarea"></input>
</div>
</div><!--CLOSE LEFT-->

<div id="main">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="MainURLtextarea"></textarea>
   <button onClick="ParseGoogleURL(document.getElementById('GoogleURLtextarea').value)" >     </button>
</div><!--CLOSE MAIN-->
```

Here is my JS:

```
function ParseGoogleURL(data)
{
    var tokenString     = data.split('/');
    var filename        = tokenString[tokenString.length - 1];
    var MainURL    = 'http://www.honeywellaidc.com/patents/pdf/' + filename + '.pdf';
    document.getElementById('MainURLtextarea').value = MainURL;
}
```

My issue is, if I try to take the ID="MainURLtextarea" and post it to the "#main" div tag it doesn't work. I've tried to replace the  with  but doesn't carry work. Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PargeGoogleURL` you are setting the `value` attribute, which is what is used for <textarea>s. However, for <div>s you should use `innerText` or `innerHTML` (as appropriate).

Comment: Genius!!! I did that for testing purposed before and totally overlooked it! Thank you!

I do have an additional question. My wrote the string so the data parses out a .pdf. If I wanted to embed the PDF in the page use <object data="" type="application/pdf"></object> - How would I get the string displayed in the data="XXXXX">??? I've tried a couple different things and nothing worked. Any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: After reading I realized that the first part didn't make sense - *The data string that is parsed out is a URL to a PDF document.*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by putting everything in an iframe instead of embedding it.

HTML:

```
<div id="MainURLtextarea"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("MainURLtextarea").innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://www.honeywellaidc.com/patents/pdf/' + filename + '.pdf" width="100%" height="768">
```